# casperJS ajax request to localhost but no post req sent

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

```
casper.then(function(){
var server = "http://localhost:3000";
var params = { link: alldata[0].link };
   var json =  this.evaluate(function(server, params) {
    try {
        __utils__.sendAJAX(server, 'POST', params, true);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log("error sending post data");
       }
    }, server, params);
 });
```

> Localhost gets hit but nothing happens. No Request while console.log(req)

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req);
    res.send('s');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you're writing a route function as you would write a middleware:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body); //this will log the body
    res.send(JSON.stringify(req.body)); //this will act like an echo route
});

app.listen(3000);
```

I am assuming you are attempting to send a JSON, if you are not, you should change your body parse. If you are attempting to send a JSON, you should modify your AJAX, because it is sending a key:value object, which is probably being translated as a form post encoding instead of a JSON, do this, just to be sure:

```
 __utils__.sendAJAX(server, 'POST',JSON.stringify(params), true);
```

Comment: params is a object with a key and a string value, and i have even used a bodyparser, I think the route is not getting a hit

Comment: let's be sure then. Download this guy, if you don't have it now you will need it later: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop then try to post anything to you url. This way we will know for sure which part is broken and focus on it.

Comment: i already did that through postman the request are being sent, while there may be some error in mine mainjs file,I have found a way to do it. soon will comment the answer